# Repository method not always giving the expected results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a weird Symfony/Doctrine bug. 
My entities structure goes like this

```
class ClassA {

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassB", inversedBy="classAs", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $classB;

}

class ClassB {

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassA", mappedBy="classB", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $classAs;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassC", inversedBy="classBs")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $classC;

}

class ClassC {

/**
* Inverse Side
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassB", mappedBy="classC", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $classBs;

/**
* Inverse Side
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassD", mappedBy="classCs", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $classDs;

}

class ClassD {

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassC", inversedBy="classDs")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $classC;

}
```

I know that in the database that ClassA (id=566208) is linked to ClassD (id=16286).

I have this very simple method in ClassARepository.

```
class ClassARepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('classA');
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        $classAs = $query->getResult();

        echo "<pre>";
        foreach ($classAs as $classA) {
            if ($classA->getId() == 566208)
            {
                echo "classA 566208\n";
                $classDs = $classA->getClassB()->getClassC()->getClassDs();
                $found = false;
                foreach ($classDs as $classD) {
                    if (16286 == $classD->getId()) {
                            $found = true;
                            echo "INFO 16286 found\n";
                    }
                }
                if (false == $found) echo "ERROR 16286 Not found\n";
            }
        }
        echo "</pre>";
  }
}
```

When I call this method in a controller no problem

```
class MyController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:ClassA')->myMethod();

    // [...]
    }
}
```

Result is

```
classA 566208
INFO 16286 found
```

But in an other part of the code

```
class MyService
{
    private function myServiceMethod()
    {
        $this->doctrine->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:ClassA')->myMethod();
    }
}
```

Result is

```
classA 566208
ERROR 16286 Not found
```

What can cause this? I a bit confused and don't know if my Doctrine is reliable.

My config 
    "php" : ">=5.5",
    "symfony/symfony" : "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm" : "~2.5",

I did a MySQLcheck everything seems ok.

**EDIT/TLDR:**

This code...

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "NORMAL\n";
$classC = $this->doctrine->getManager()->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:ClassC')->find(7);
$classDs = $classC->getClassDs();
$found = false;
foreach ($classDs as $classD) {
    if (16286 == $classD->getId()) {
            $found = true;
            echo "INFO 16286 found\n";
    }
}
if (false == $found) echo "ERROR 16286 Not found\n";

echo "INVERSED\n";
$classDs = $this->doctrine->getManager()->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:ClassD')->findBy(array("classC" => 7));
$found = false;
foreach ($classDs as $classD) {
    if (16286 == $classD->getId()) {
            $found = true;
            echo "INFO 16286 found\n";
    }
}
if (false == $found) echo "ERROR 16286 Not found\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

...gives...

```
NORMAL
ERROR 16286 Not found
INVERSED
INFO 16286 found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was queries were executed before the service myMethod call and Doctrine put in cache some subparts of these queries.

**The solution was to ask Entity Manager to clear its cache.**

```
$this->doctrine->getManager()->clear();
$this->doctrine->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('MyCoreBundle:ClassA')->myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever query for this id, you don't have to and shouldn't loop over every table record if its not needed. Something like this:

`$this->doctrine->getManager->getRepository->('MyCoreBundle:ClassA')->find(16286)`

is much more efficient. And you can pick the entityManager from inside the repository and get a repository for classC and query that with the id directly, too.

Are you sure nothing is changing the relations in between the two method calls?

Im using Doctrine for some time now and also in production but i had no such issue yet.

Comment: No I need to loop on all ClassA objects but I found something was missing for this particular id 566208. I don't know if other object have the same problem.

Comment: Nothing is changing between the 2 method calls.